# How to get everything after the domain name into a string

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

My goal is to get everything after the domain name into a string. As in mysite.com/page/page2 would result in a string "page/page2". That I can do, however it starts giving me problems when, for example, the site is in a subfolder and not in root, then the folder the site is in will also be included in the string and if I'm not using mod_rewrite to get pretty links, it will also add index.php to the string.

So, I would need a trick or two to make the script understand whether or not the site is in a subfolder such as mysite.com/sitefolder/page/page2 and that it would still result in a string

```
page/page2
```

If the site doesn not use mod_rewrite and the url is mysite.com/sitefolder/index.php/page/page2, it would still result in a string

```
page/page2
```

Keep in mind that I have URL and USE_MOD_REWRITE defined in a config file, so no need for magic. I just have no idea how to go about getting that string. I know I could do $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get the string, but then index.php would still be in it. I'm sorry if I didn't explain well enough, but all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- get the path by parsing the request uri
- remove eventual script name from the end of the string (e.g. index.php)
- rtrim any trailing slashes

  ```
  $request = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  $path = $request["path"];
  $result = rtrim(str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $path), '/');
  ```

EDIT

```
$request = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$path = $request["path"];

$result = trim(str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $path), '/');

$result = explode('/', $result);
$max_level = 2;
while ($max_level < count($result)) {
    unset($result[0]);
}
$result = '/'.implode('/', $result);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Any idea on how to detect if the entire site is in a subfolder? Currently, if in subfolder, it will output the folder name, too.

Comment: I guess you would need to define a maximum level of subfolder in the website... See edit ;)

Comment: "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" - I think the loop is not exactly a good idea :D

Comment: I think you left rtrim() where for the second solution it should be trim()

Answer (score 2):

You could use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and then modify the string with PHP's `substr()` function. So, put the URI into a variable and then run that function to remove the first X number of characters (domain name length) from the beginning and X number of characters from the end (index.php = 9).

For example:

`$new_url = substr($uri_variable, 10, -9);`

Where `$uri_variable` is the `$_SERVER[`REQUEST_URI']`, 10 is the character after the domain name and -9 is the characters in index.php.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: This is way easier.