# redirect www.domain.com/example.com to example.com

Tags: php, redirect

Many years ago i read there was a simple php script that would redirect your website like this `http://example.com/google.com` to `google.com` and it would work for any domain on the  right  of the forward slash. I forgot what this script is or where to find it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please learn how to accept answers ... if you have no idea what I'm talking about [click here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170679)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create an htaccess file in your document root, and add this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9-.]+)$ http://$1/ [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your redirect to be permanent, use a 301 redirect.  This is search engine safe and smart browsers can upgrade bookmarks using this.

e.g. http://www.phpjunkyard.com/tutorials/php-redirect.php

```
<?php 
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    header("Location: http://www.New-Website.com"); 
?>
```

**EDIT** (Response to comments below)

This post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775374/how-to-get-everything-after-the-domain-name-into-a-string) will be helpful in building up the domain to redirect to.  If we build that into a function such as `get_url()`, you could then change the above to

```
<?php 
    my_url = get_url();

    // CHECK IT IS A SAFE URL

    // REDIRECT
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    header("Location: " . my_url); 
?>
```

Comment: @ManseUK The OP asked for PHP not htaccess... you can use $_SERVER variables or similar to build the domain. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php