# Redirect to Wordpress based based on custom field

Tags: wordpress, url

Some of my wordpress posts have a custom field called a QR shortcode.  I want to be able to redirect any URL request when someone goes to domain.com/QRCODEVALUE, and have them directed to the post with the corresponding QR code.  Is there any way to do this? I don't even know where to start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but the logic should help you get somewhere.  Grab the URL request path, remove the trailing slash if it exists, and query posts where the custom field contains QRCODEVALUE:

```
<?php
function my_redirect() {
    $request = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $path = $request["path"];
    $path = explode('/', $path);
    $length = count($path);
    $result = $path[$length-1];
    $id;
    $query = new WP_Query( array('meta_key' => 'QRCODEVALUE', 'meta_value' => $result) );
    if($query->have_posts()): while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
        $id = $post->ID;
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $id ) ); 
    exit;
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_redirect');
```

Reference: [Get Everything After Domain Name into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775374/how-to-get-everything-after-the-domain-name-into-a-string)

Comment: I haven't tested it either, but the answer above seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

Is domain.com/QRCODEVALUE a page? If so, you could do something like this:

```
function my_redirect() {
    if ( is_page( 'QRCODEVALUE' ) ) {

        // Get the ID of the post with the corresponding QR code here
        // Save the post ID to $post_id

        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post_id ) ); 
        exit;
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_redirect' );
```

Comment: No, domain.com/QRCODEVALUE is redirecting to the page that contains QRCODEVALUE in a custom field.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow actually...?

Comment: So in 600 of my posts, each one has a field called QR code, which is a random code.  I want people to be able to get to that post by entering that custom field in the URL.  So if one post has the value "dkh83d82d" they should be able to see it by going to mydomain.com/dkh83d82d