# Add params to query string in a clean way in php

Tags: php, parameters, get, addition

I'd like to find a **clean** if possibile (without too much string manipulation preg_*)

I know that to replace a parameter I would do

```
$_GET['info'] = "newinfo";
```

and to remove a parameter:

```
unset($_GET['info']);
```

so is there something like that that I can use?

of course after I've "unset" or "set" I'm building a new query.
(http_build_query).

At the end I'm trying to make this:

> /index.php?foo=bar

to

> /index.php?foo=bar&info=newinfo

Comment: I'm quite confused. What's your question? `so is there something like that that I can use?` isn't specific enough and I have no idea what you're trying to get across. Maybe give the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a read

Comment: @IsThisJavascript yeah, sorry, I've added more info, my bad

Comment: What's wrong with `http_build_query`?

Comment: Also, you are missing a quote on the `$_GET['info']`

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "clean"? What about copying `$_GET` to a new array, update as desired, and then `http_build_query()`?

Comment: You should never meddle with input data sources (`$_GET`, `$_POST`, etc.). Best is you consider them read-only and operate on a copy of them.

Comment: There's a few examples on [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) which are quite handy for easily manipulating a path.

Comment: @PatrickQ I mean that I've seen several ways that use some preg_match(...) and manipulating strings, their code looked very messy.

Comment: @JustCarty Can I add new params using `http_build_query()` ?

Comment: @Hexer10 Have you read the docs? Just add a new option to `$_GET` and then build using that. For instance `$_GET['new'] = 'value'; http_build_query($_GET);` But as @Dormilich said, don't mess with that data. Instead store it in a new variable such as `$get`.

Comment: @JustCarty that's what I needed! I'm not used in PHP sorry for the (useless) question.

Comment: @Hexer10 So, basically [exactly what I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734204/add-params-to-query-string-in-a-clean-way#comment86482542_49734204).  Cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$get = $_GET;
$get['new'] = 'some value';

function getPath()
{
    // Stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775529/3578036
    $request = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $path = $request["path"];
    return rtrim(str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $path), '/');
}

header("Location: " . getPage() . http_build_query($get));
```

The above code will create a query string and append it to the current URL and redirect to that location. Obviously, you can change the location that you redirect to by replacing the getPage() function result and putting your own result there, this just demonstrates the premise of the answer.

The docs for [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) are a very good place to start.
Effectively, what it will do is convert an associative array into an HTTP query string.